# Spring SOAP web service integration test error: no endpoint mapping found. The soap service itself works, the problem is with the test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, integration-testing

I created a soap web service with Spring WS. When I run my application and send SOAP requests to the endpoint I get the correct response. So the service itself is working.

Now I want to write integration tests using Spring's MockWebServiceClient, but I'm getting the error:

```
org.springframework.ws.NoEndpointFoundException: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://tempuri.org/}StartSessionGetOffers]
```

Because the service works when I spin up the application, but not when running the test, I looked for differences in the logs at start-up. When the application spins up, I see logs related to soap service mappings, which are absent from the test context:

```
INFO  ServletRegistrationBean - Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/soapWebService/*]
```

My understanding what that the @ContextConfiguration annotation on the test class was responsible for registering the soap service on applicationContext, which is then used by the mock Client to call the service i.e mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);

The problem could also be related to the how the request / response is being generated in the integration test. I'm using the RequestCreators class, and passing it the same soap request xml that I have tested and know works. The request looks to be generated correctly.

But it's not working, and I'm out of ideas.

My test class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { WebServiceConfig.class })
public class InteractProxyEndpointTest {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    MockWebServiceClient mockClient;


    @Before
    public void createClient() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void interactEndpointTest() throws IOException {
        final RequestCreator requestCreator; // Creator for the request
        final ResponseMatcher responseMatcher; // Matcher for the response

        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);

        Resource requestPayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:com/lmig/dragon/controller/test/requestPayload.xml");
        Resource responsePayload = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:com/lmig/dragon/controller/test/responsePayload.xml");

        requestCreator = RequestCreators
                .withSoapEnvelope(requestPayLoad);


        responseMatcher = ResponseMatchers.soapEnvelope(responsePayload);

        // Calls the endpoint
        mockClient.sendRequest(requestCreator).andExpect(responseMatcher);
    }
}
```

My WebServiceConfig

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<Servlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet,"/soapWebService/*");
  }

  @Bean(name = "interactOffers")
  public DefaultWsdl11Definition interactWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema interactOffersSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    definition.setPortTypeName("InteractOffersPort");
    definition.setTargetNamespace("http://tempuri.org/StartSessionGetOffers");
    definition.setLocationUri("/soapWebService");
    definition.setSchema(interactOffersSchema);
    return definition;
  }

  @Bean
  public XsdSchema interactOffersSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("interact-offers.xsd"));
  }
}
```

requestPayload.xml

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:nba="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NBAInteract.DataContracts">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:StartSessionGetOffers>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:request>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:EmployeeId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:LMCustId></nba:LMCustId>
            <nba:LMHouseholdId>/nba:LMHouseholdId>
            <nba:SessionId></nba:SessionId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:CdiHouseholdId></nba:CdiHouseholdId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:EventName></nba:EventName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:LMInteractionChannel></nba:LMInteractionChannel>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:OfferCount></nba:OfferCount>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <nba:UserAuxCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:StartSessionGetOffers>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Test logs:**

```
INFO  DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener]
INFO  DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@445629, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1b9a632, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@1d250c6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1f50bcc, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@126e945, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1a65a25, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@c562f7, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@18ba8c8, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@1bb137d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@9d0b9d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@1301423, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@1112965]
INFO  GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1c758ac: startup date [Sat May 04 21:25:01 PDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.lmig.dragon.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e2d774] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ca20d2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  AnnotationActionEndpointMapping - Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
INFO  SaajSoapMessageFactory - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
INFO  SaajSoapMessageFactory - Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
WARN  EndpointNotFound - No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://tempuri.org/}StartSessionGetOffers]
ERROR MockWebServiceClient - Could not send request
org.springframework.ws.NoEndpointFoundException: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://tempuri.org/}StartSessionGetOffers]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:217) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient.sendRequest(MockWebServiceClient.java:178) ~[spring-ws-test-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.lmig.dragon.controller.test.InteractProxyEndpointTest.interactEndpointTest(InteractProxyEndpointTest.java:60) [test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
INFO  GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@1c758ac: startup date [Sat May 04 21:25:01 PDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy
```

---

**Full application start-up logs (When the service works as expected):**

```
INFO  PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='vault', propertySources=[LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource {name='secret/np/us-consumer-markets/uscm-contact-center-technology/trove/test/test/trove-credentials'}, LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource {name='secret/np/us-consumer-markets/uscm-contact-center-technology/trove/test/test/application'}]}
INFO  Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
INFO  AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@10d6318: startup date [Fri May 03 13:44:03 PDT 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@959ece
INFO  GenericScope - BeanFactory id=3c934013-f2bf-3e58-ac35-c5b28f255634
INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.lmig.dragon.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2cbed7af] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ba6210d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  AnnotationActionEndpointMapping - Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
INFO  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3285f0b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO  TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 443 (http)
INFO  Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
INFO  StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO  StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
INFO  AprLifecycleListener - The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nice Systems\NICE Player Codec Pack\\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\IC73\Java\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Avaya\IC73\bin\;C:\Users\n0230962\Desktop\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NICE Systems\NICE Player Release 6\\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Citrix\Virtual Desktop Agent\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\n0230962\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\n0230962\Desktop\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.1.RELEASE;;.]
INFO  [/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO  ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1250 ms
INFO  ServletRegistrationBean - Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/soapWebService/*]
INFO  ServletRegistrationBean - Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
INFO  FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
INFO  RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@10d6318: startup date [Fri May 03 13:44:03 PDT 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@959ece
[org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
INFO  AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=10d6318,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
INFO  Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
INFO  NioSelectorPool - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO  TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 443 (http) with context path ''
INFO  Application - Started Application in 4.705 seconds (JVM running for 5.539)
```

Comment: Is there some `WsdlDefinition` bean in your application linked to the `/soapWebService` uri? If so, is it present in the application context?

Comment: @Michiel Originally I did have a WsdlDefinition bean, which I understood exposed the wsdl from the service url, but since I have no need to expose the wsdl, I removed the bean, and the service continued to work.  I just added those definitions back (see updated WebServiceConfig above), and still seeing same error. Do you have reason to believe that WSDL definition bean is required for the integration test? Because it does not appear to be necessary for the soap service itself to function. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

add @ComponentScan to your WebServiceConfig,it can be likes this:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter 
{
....
}
```